# How to write Ubuntu in boot.ini?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 12.10

I have Windows XP.

It has ntldr and boot.ini on

```
multi 0 disk 0 rdisk 0 partition 1
```

and loads Windows from

```
multi 0 disk 0 rdisk 0 partition 3
```

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the second hard drive and I don't know what its partition number is. I think something like

```
multi 0 disk 0 rdisk 2 partition 1
```

or

```
multi 0 disk 0 rdisk 2 partition 3
```

because I have it partitioned like this:

1. 10 GB, ext4. (I think this is Ubuntu's main partition)
2. 5 GB, swap
3. 85 GB, ext4 (I think this is Ubuntu's home folder)
4. 365 GB, NTFS (for holding files)

I did it as here (like sda 5,6,7) but with higher volume and also I have same sda 2,3,4 but with other volumes which are partitions of another hard disk: http://help.ubuntu.ru/_detail/wiki/install_12_10/016.png?id=wiki%3Ainstall_ubuntu_12_10

What I want to know it, what do I need to write in boot.ini to choose Ubuntu like second string after my WinXP when I turn on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [on this page](http://startubuntu.ru/?p=94002)

Copy the partition table from your Ubuntu partition to the Windows partition (you'll need to mount your windows drive first):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/me/windowsxp/ubuntu.boot bs=512 count=1
```

Then add this line:

```
C:\ubuntu.boot="Ubuntu"
```

to `c:\boot.ini` so that when bootmgr.exe runs (if the Windows partition is higher in the BIOS boot priority), it will have enough information to redirect to the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.